# Subgroup generated by elements of finite order

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let G be any group and let H be the subgroup of G generated by all elements of finite order. Is there a name for H?

Comment: In case $G$ is abelian, this is the **torsion subgroup** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_subgroup, and I suspect the same language would be understood for non-abelian groups.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think *torsion subgroup* is only used when the set of torsion elements form a subgroup, which is not always the case. I am not aware of the subgroup generated by the torsion elements having any particularly interesting properties in general.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The non-abelian case is quite different, since it is quite common for torsion elements to generate the whole group!

Comment: I do not think torsion subgroup would usually be used in the case of non-Abelian groups since the set of elements of finite order in an infinite non-Abelian group is not usually a subgroup, so to call $H$ the torsion subgroup could be misleading. Note however, that the subgroup $H$ is a normal subgroup . Unlike the Abelian case, $G/H$ need not be torsion free  in general.

Comment: More generally the torsion elements form a subgroup in nilpotent groups.

Comment: Thanks. I asked the question because of an example for which G/H has nonidentity elements of finite order.

Comment: One think we could naively expect from the subgroup $X(G)$ generated by the torsion in a  group $G$ (it is obviously characteristic, hence normal) would be that the quotient $G/X(G)$ is torsion-free. But it's not the case, as simple examples show. We can define the largest torsion-free quotient of $G$ as $G/Y(G)$, with $X(G)\subset Y(G)$ but I don't see a "constructive" way to describe $Y(G)$ similar to the definition of $X(G)$ except using a transfinite induction.

Comment: @user82540 I don't understand if you ask an example for which $X(G)\neq Y(G)$ (i.e., for which $G/X(G)$ is not torsion-free, or if you claim to have such an example. An example is the amalgam of an infinite dihedral group with an infinite cyclic group over a common proper infinite cyclic subgroup. Then $G/X(G)$ is finite cyclic. Example: $G=<x,y,z|x^2=y^2=1,xy=z^k>$. Then $G/X(G)$ is cyclic of order $k$.

Comment: In fact, $X(G)$ (to follow the notation of @YCor) is not just characteristic, but fully invariant, since given any endomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to G$, the image of an element of finite order must be of finite order, so $\varphi(X(G))\subseteq X(G)$. It is even more, since the construction is functorial, in that if $G$ and $H$ are groups, and $\varphi\colon G\to H$ is a group homomorphism, then $\varphi(X(G))\subseteq X(H)$, since the image of the generating set of $X(G)$ lies inside $X(H)$.

Comment: @YCor I had an example, but was curious if the subgroup has a proper name.

Comment: OK. I don't really know what do do with this notion. We can elaborate some questions, e.g. if we define it in a transfinite way, $X^1(G)=X(G)$, $X^2(G)$ the inverse image of $X(G/X(G))$ in $G$, etc., and wonder if it can stop after an arbitrary number of steps.